# Add button column in Html.Grid

Tags: html, button, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib-grid

I am very new to MVC. I have an Html.Grid with some column in it.I want to add a new column with its heading as "New Column".This column will have a button for each row.The button should be disabled based on the value of another column.For example,if 'status' column for a row is "complete",then the button should be enabled otherwise it should be disabled. When the button is clicked,"myMethod" in "MyController" will be called.
The existing code in my View looks like this:

```
Html.Grid(Model.Results)
            .RowAttributes(row => new Hash(@class => row.Item.Priority1 ? "redgrid" : row.IsAlternate ? "alternategrid" : "grid"))
            .Columns(column =>
            {
                column.For(c =>
                    (c.ExistsInPatRec == true) ?
                    Html.ActionLink(c.CaseNumber.ToString(), "Details", new { id = c.CaseNumber }, new { target = "_blank" })
                    : Html.Label(c.CaseNumber.ToString())
                    )
                    .Named("Case Number").SortColumnName("CaseNumber")
                    .Encode(false)
                    ;
//I have to add my column here.It will be disabled if "Status"="Incomplete"

                column.For(c => c.Status).Named("Status").SortColumnName("Status")
                    .Attributes(x =>
                    {
                        if (x.Item.Status == "Complete")
                            return new Hash(style => "background-color:#33CC00");
                        else if (x.Item.Status == "Incomplete")
                            return new Hash(style => "background-color:orange");
                        else
                            return new Hash(style => "");
                    });
                column.For(c => c.SomeId);
```

I have added this line:

```
column.For(c => "<button onclick='location.href='www.gmail.com';'>gmail</button>").Named("My New Column").Encode(false);
```

but it's not working.When I click the button,it doesnt take me to the link.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Does the disable and enable work fine currently?

Comment: I am not able to add the column,in the first place.Enabling/disabling is secondary. I do not know how to add the button in the grid that calls the Action in a Controller. A sample code that adds the column with a button in it will be helpful.

Comment: So your column is appearing with button and not taking you to link, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did not yet go through your entire code but try this:

Change:

```
column.For(c => "<button onclick='location.href='www.gmail.com';'>gmail</button>").Named("My New Column").Encode(false);
```

To:

```
column.For(c => "<button onclick=\"javascript:window.open('http://gmail.com');\">gmail</button>").Named("My New Column").Encode(false);
```

This should at least make your links work. Your links were not working since your buttons were not properly formed.

To trigger Controller Actions, you need to use the following type of code.

```
column.For(c => "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Go Somewhere Else\" onclick=\"location.href='<%: Url.Action(\"myMethod\", \"myController\") %>'\" />").Encode(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.How would I call an Action in a Controller from the button now? And how can i enable/disable the button?

Comment: I am not entirely sure about the exact semantics but to disable a button you would write the button as `<button disabled='disabled'>Hi</button>` so you just need to add/remove the `disabled='disabled'` depending upon the condition.

Comment: @user1550951: I've added the code that adds a button which can trigger an action.

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478797/add-button-in-mvccontrib-grid-column